# c++ ‘total’ was not declared in this scope. MAIN

Tags: c++, function, program-entry-point, declare

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int population(int current_pop)
{
   int Time;
   int birth;
   int immigrant;
   int death;
   int total;
   Time = 24*60*60*365; // convet day to second
   birth = Time/8;
   death = Time/12;
   immigrant = Time/33; // calculate the rate of the death, birth,immigrant
   total = birth+immigrant-death+current_pop; // make sum
   return total;
}

int main() {
   int current_pop = 1000000;
   population(current_pop); //test
   cout << total << endl;
}
```

it just show that error: ‘total’ was not declared in this scope
     cout << total << endl;

Why? And If i already declared a value should i declare it again in the main function?

Comment: Your population function doesn't even exist after you return from it.  All that remains is the return value which in this case has the information you are looking for.  You should read some articles on scope in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error said, you declared `total` variable inside `population()` which will not be available in `main()` function. `population()` function will have its own scope so that any variables declared inside it, only accessible there.
To make it available then you need to declare it inside `main()`.

```
int main() {
    ...
    int total = population(current_pop);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables with the same name in different functions store different values. They are totally unrelated. It needs some getting used to, when starting to program. Try this:

```
int total = population(current_pop); //test
```

Comment: `cout << population(current_pop) << endl;` would also work.